# Different kinds of pita?

Tags: middle-eastern-cuisine, pita

[image]I my family doesn't make pita at home. My dad always had soft fluffy pita. Now I grocery shop for myself I noticed some pita is thin. I googled different kinds of pita. I'm only fluent in English so I think maybe I'm bad at Google because of the language barrier.I don't really know how to eat it. I eat pita like a utensil to pick up food. So if it's not soft and like a sponge, what do you do with it and does it have a name?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the Pita that you buy from your grocery store? I am not sure what kind you are buying - for example, *kubooz* is softer variety often used to make rolls like the popular *shwarma*.

Comment: okay, I added the picture. The last time I ate out they gave me the shawarma in thin pita and I was confused lol. I think this is the name of the pita though: kubooz. looks like what I eat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thin pita you find a lot in stores is called just that: "thin pita".  I tend to call it "Egyptian pita" because it's a style that's very common there, due partly to the [price controls on bread](https://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContent/1/64/462877/Egypt/Politics-/Egypt-to-enforce-price-controls-on-unsubsidised-br.aspx).  It's very popular in other countries, including the US where I live, because it's very dry and lasts on the shelf for considerably longer that other, "fluffier" styles of pita.

I've found two good ways to eat other foods with it.  One is to treat it like a tortilla, tearing pieces of the pita and folding them between my fingers and thumb to pick stuff up.  The other is cutting it up, frying it, and using it as pita chips.

Comment: Cool! Now I know 

Answer (score 3):

"Pita" is simply a name for the shape. It's a loaf of bread which is approximately round, and the diameter is much larger than the height. Any consistency of bread could be baked in that shape, and would be called a pita.

So, the supermarket is not wrong in selling you a bread of different consistency than what you're accustomed to - it's the shape that makes a pita, not the texture or recipe.

> does it have a name?

No, there wouldn't be a special name. There are no special, recognized subtypes of pita. Of course, people who bake more than one kind will differentiate them in some ways, for example you can come across a grandma's hand-written recipe collection which contains a recipe for "pita with milk", another one for "holiday pita" and a third for just "pita". But it will likely be a different recipe from the next grandma's holiday pita.

> what do you do with it

Just eat it, in any of the dozens ways you'd eat any other bread. I suppose you don't eat other types of bread differently based on shape (except maybe for a few obvious situations like not making a hamburger out of a pretzel*) - there is no need to eat pita bread differently from any other bread just because it's shaped like a pita and not like a boule, a pullman loaf, a roll or a fougasse.

* here I mean the original German meaning of the word "pretzel", so defined by the shape, not by the presence of a lye crust

Comment: That's kind of like saying you can eat pita however and you can't. Or you can Chinese with a fork. It's like immoral. If I go to middle eastern restaurant now a days in America they have a wrap and I'm like what is that. I feel like this a very western view and therefore not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You might be seeing ‘pocket pita’ which is the first type that I was familiar with.

It tends to be dryer and firmer than non-pocket pita bread.  As it’s cooked, it is allowed to puff up so that when you cut into it, the two sides separate easily (it may require a little bit of prying).

As such, you can cut the whole round in half into two half-circles and then fill each side with whatever sandwich-type fillings you like.

It’s also possible to cut this type of pita into quarters, optionally separate the two sides, and then bake into crackers so it can be used to scoop up dips.

Comment: Pocket pita can be fluffy too.  There's both a fluffy style ("Israeli") and a thin style ("Syrian/Egyptian").

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the thin harder kind of pita (might work with the fluffy kind as well) you cut it open part way along its edge and slip you food in, making it a filled pocket which you can hold in your hand as if it was a sandwich.

Where I live the fluffy kind is not common, filled pocket breads were introduced with what is known as Donner, but was called shoarma when it reached us. Grilled sliced meat, served in small strips with sauces to be added into the pocket between bites.
Fillings with sauce do work but tend to spill out of the bottom.

Comment: How do you like to eat the thin pita?

Comment: It is useful if you want to eat thing that would escape from a sandwich.